# How to validate the RefreshToken programmatically in Google?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are using Google Ads API and we wanted to validate the Refresh token programmatically, as using a incorrect refresh token or expired refresh token is taking lot of time before giving an exception(60 mins approx or even more) and hence causing a 504 TIMEOUT. Also there is a limitation on number of refresh token that we can create which is at max [50 refresh token at a time and if we create new 51st refresh token then the oldest one will expire](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration). And hence chances of getting into this issue is more likely so we wanted to know if there is some API via which we can validate and then take appropriate actions instead of direct calling Google Ads API and getting into TIMEOUT ISSUE.

We also reached out to Google ads forum for this requirement and suggested to reach out GCP support ref link to Question asked: https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/tqOdXsnL5NI

We tried calling [listaccessiblecustomers](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v10/CustomerService#listaccessiblecustomers) .
And we were expecting to get some invalid Exception in some ms or some secs so that we can log it for Error notification to our customers instead, after calling the API the call got stuck for almost 61 mins and then 504 TIMEOUT occurred.

Comment: 1) Stack Overflow is not Google Cloud Support. 2) AFAIK there is no API to validate a Google OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token. 3) Your design is not correct. You should only capture one refresh token and then use that token until it becomes invalid. At that point, the user must reauthorize your application. 4) I have **never** seen an invalid refresh token cause long delays with an API. Something else is going on with your code. Create an example to prove otherwise and post on GitHub: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You really need to post your code. You said you tried calling the listaccessiblecustomers service, but how? Are you using the client libraries? If so, what language are you even using?

You need to put in a bit of effort if you need some help. Remember, we can't see what you see on the screen in front of you.